# How to break Universal Re-Encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

> Let p be a prime, and g be an element of $ℤ^*p$ of prime order q.
>   Let x ∈ ℤq be the private key, and $h = g^x$ (mod p) be the public key.
>
> To encrypt a message m ∈ $ℤ^*p$, pick two random values r, s ∈ ℤq, and compute the ciphertext as follows:
>
> (a, b, c, d) = ($g^r$, $h^r$, $g^s$, $mh^s$).
>
> Now, let assume :
>
> ```
> p = 0x8000048d1d71b57838b7d90ebc63b8c853f3af1af87ce2db5593f3386ae5139d040d3844e31db723d39cdd7717c8cffc26f6f877b5c85ca8e595ca687c07c773
> a = 0x21068b690f5438360063bb80799a95af7bbb83fa399376af9ad21e0cef3d5233aa313fe1960ccfd87e8a4b1dba0e053d89bfebd4bc57170147462fafef44c9c7
> b = 0x436c161645052a76c1f7c976da63f61987f5f9bf7cb810a0e6fb1ea593aa9397c7b7cb0488f0f14cf93c79eef967a4b2a39388da1a357077d30a6f8b2a2c97e7
> c = 0x7dd53b07c05ea2aca88bcbdd58601fa344918848107431ae7710542ea625abb335c27352c1bd2ef01359adb19b1bee77edc07ab0b41b9766392fc154f7891268
> d = 0x1a50308011b409460d504cc7cddd61cdff1bda0774d1329b59606df274bce81a7e4b15830ddd4e684e3f2422d36bd52220134881db560be0a34c76a9c5bbb6be
> ```
>
> are a valid ciphertext σ = (a, b, c, d).

I want to compute another valid ciphertext σ′ = (a′, b′, c′, d′) such that:

1. σ and σ′ decrypt to the same message;
2. a ≠ a′ and b ≠ b′ and c ≠ c′ and d ≠ d′.

How can I do it?

**Note: You require neither g nor h to solve this challenge!**

Comment: Possibly relevant http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18954/553

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing $g$ and $h$ we can do as the original paper [says](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~pgolle/papers/univrenc.pdf):

> Pick $m,n$ random, both from $\mathbb{Z}_q$ where $n \neq 1, c^m \neq 1, d^m \neq 1$. Then $\sigma' = (c^n, d^n,ac^m, bd^m) \pmod p$ will do.

The decryption routine is also in that paper.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you do not want to break anything at all. Universal re-encryption pursues the idea that anyone given a ciphertext can WITHOUT knowledge of the public key re-randomize a given ciphertext to an unlinkable ciphertext to the same message. Thus you include an additional encryption of the identity (1 in the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$) with independent randomness (this are the elements $a$ and $b$) in the ciphertext and use the homomorphic property of ElGamal for re-encryption without a public key.

And that is what you need to do: Given ciphertext $(a,b,c,d)$ choose new independent randomness $k, k'$ (from $\mathbb{Z}_p$) and compute $(a^k, b^k,a^{k'}c,b^{k'}d)$. It is easy to see that this is again a valid ciphertext and indeed independent from the one you started with.

And as @Henno Brandsma mentions it may not be a too bad idea to first take a look at the paper (which in general is a rather useful advice).

Comment: Can one "use the homomorphic property of ElGamal for re-encryption without" the group? ​ If no, then it seems like getting Universal re-encryption this way wold require the existence of a [Bellagio algorithm](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2011/136/) to generate the group. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Nope, not without the group. But here you assume that all public keys share the same group parameters and thus the description of the group is known, but not the individual public key.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute $\sigma'$ as follows:

$$\sigma' = (a\cdot g^{r'},b'\cdot h^{r'},c'\cdot g^{s'},d'\cdot h^{s'})$$

where $r',s'$ are chosen randomly from $\mathbb Z^*_p$. This produces the following ciphertext, which decrypts to $m$:

$$\sigma' = (g^{r+r'},h^{r+r'},g^{s+s'},m\cdot h^{s+s'})$$

Comment: how did you compute $σ′$ without having $b′$, $c′$, $d′$, $h$ and $g$?

Answer (score 1):

$h=g^x$ so $h^s={g^s}^x$ so for decryption of $m$ we have:

> $$m=d\cdot c^{-x}$$

I think $a$ and $b$ are not necessary.

Also, there exist lot of valid ciphertexts. As cygnusv mentioned you can choose $r',s'$ randomly and this is a valid ciphertext:

> $$\sigma' = (g^{r+r'},h^{r+r'},g^{s+s'},m\cdot h^{s+s'})$$

Comment: Can you provide me one $σ′$ values plz?

Comment: @Abraham, See DrLecter's answer.