# ElGamal re-encrypts data

Tags: elgamal-encryption

I try to learn ElGamal re-encrypts scheme and I have a question about the example: [How is a re-encryption done with elGamal?.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43426/66998)

- The $g$ value of Alice must be the same as $g$ value of Bob or not?
- And what about of Prime $p$ value for Alice and Bob? Alice.$p$ must be the same as Bob.$p$ or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and Yes.${}$

Comment: Ok, thank you!  
  I try test it:  
  2. Bob reencrypts (x,w) as (x′,w′) with x′=xg^u, w′=wy^u(x′)^b.  
  I use BigInteger.  I look that x1>0, ok but w1=0, becourse x1 > p:  
  var x1 = g.modPow(u, p).multiply(x);  
  var tmpB = y.modPow(u, p).multiply(w);  
  var w1 = x1.modPow(b,p).multiply(tmpB);  
  this w1 = 0  
Where I mistake? –

Comment: Eugene, CryptoSO is not programming site. You can ask your programming question with your programming codes in Stackoverflow.